# Trying to avoid loops and improving function's speed

Tags: functions, performance-tuning

The target is to get a `True` for all `lists` that have all elements out of canonical order. 
First I wrote a `For` loop and then a function that has not loops

```
lcd[cc_List] := Module[{ccp = {}, cco = {}, i, lccp, res = 0, lcd},
                ccp = cc;
                cco = Sort[ccp];
                lccp = Length[ccp];
                For[i = 1, i <= lccp, i++, If[cco[[i]] == ccp[[i]], res++]];
                lcd = If[res != 0, False, True];
                lcd]
```

Then without

```
aeo[lst_List] := 
 If[Apply [Times, Flatten[MapIndexed[# - #2 & , Ordering[lst]]]] != 0,
   True, False]
```

Testing both with

```
ldldp = Table[RandomSample[Alphabet[], 6], 10^6];
```

Giving theese results

```
AbsoluteTiming[lcd /@ ldldp;]    {53.7615, Null}
AbsoluteTiming[aeo /@  ldldp;]   {49.6765, Null}
```

So my question is if is possible to use more efficient functions to do this job.
Thanks

Comment: Do sublists have fixed length?

Comment: @Kuba  Yes, all sublists have the same number of elements

Comment: Do you really have to multiply? `tst[lst_] := FreeQ[Ordering[lst] - Range[Length[lst]], 0]`

Comment: @ J.M. Of course I don't need, good this run clear, sharp  thanks sincerely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

```
xyz = Function[
     array
  ,  Not /@ ( Or @@@ MapThread[SameQ, {array, Sort /@ array}, 2] )
]

xyz2 = Function[array
  , 0 != # & /@ Times @@@ Unitize[
        Ordering /@ array - ConstantArray[Range[6], Length@array]
    ]
]
```

```
ldldp = Table[RandomSample[Alphabet[], 6], 10^5];

(my2 = xyz2@ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming

(my = xyz @ ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming

(cd = abc /@ ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming

(op = lcd /@ ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming

my === m2 === cd === op
```

> {0.186604, Null}
>
> {0.273875, Null}
>
> {0.629395, Null}
>
> {2.13767, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Good  really fast and sharp!  I made the way step by step to understand and learn. Really thankful Kuba!

Answer (score 2):

A simple change but considerable timing improvement.

```
abc[lst_List] :=
 If[Apply[Times, Ordering[lst] - Range@Length@lst] != 0,
  True, False]
```

Comment: Using `OrderedQ[]` might be more direct.

Comment: @Chris Degnen Really good improovement, I can see MapIndexed is slow. Thanks

Comment: @AnxonPués please take a [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). It is a good habit to hold on with an accept in order to not discourage others, but upvote instead.

Comment: Also the `If[...,True,False]` idiom doesn't do anything and can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use but `Integer`s, you make @Kuba's result even faster by employing the following `CompiledFunction`:

```
cxyz2 = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}},
   Times @@ (Ordering[a] - Range[Length[a]]) != 0,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

On my machine (4 core), this is 20 times faster than `xyz2`.

Preparing the data

```
With[{alphabet = Alphabet[]},
   p = AssociationThread[alphabet -> Range[Length[alphabet]]];
   ldldp = Table[RandomSample[alphabet, 6], 10^5];
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[Map[Lookup[p, #] &, ldldp]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.097882, Null} *)
```

Conversion time is not insignificant, so this method relies on the fact that the encoding was in `Integers` in the first place.

```
(cmy2 = cxyz2@data); // AbsoluteTiming
(my2 = xyz2@ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming
(my = xyz@ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming
(cd = abc /@ ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming
(op = lcd /@ ldldp); // AbsoluteTiming
cmy2 === my === my2 === cd === op

(* {0.01136, Null} *)
(* {0.260086, Null} *)
(* {0.285857, Null} *)
(* {0.48367, Null} *)
(* {2.12977, Null} *)
(* True *)
```